# PHP Object property won't update with new value

Tags: php, object, laravel-5

I have an object in which I want to update the id to hash it, to then use it in URLs.
However, trying to update the object property just results in it being 0.

If I set it with just a number, for example 5 it works. Has me confused.

So not working:

```
$lead = Lead::with('user', 'source', 'industry', 'status')->where('status_id', $status)->get();

foreach($lead as $key => $leads)
{
    $lead[$key]->id = Hashids::encode($leads->id);
}
```

Does work:

```
foreach($lead as $key => $leads)
{
    $lead[$key]->id = '14';
}
```

Hoping someone can shed some light on this one. I'm using Laravel 5.4 with Junity\Hashids package. I've not had problems with this before, just in this instance.
Thanks!

---

Portion of var_dump($lead) after foreach.

```
attributes:protected: 
    (array) [13 elements]
    id: (string) A5WQqPZ7j8D
    zoho_lead: (integer) 2709828000000210400 
    bname: (string) test
    tname: (string) 
    file: (string) 6cTaDu8FE0Sirwq.png
    source_id: (integer) 11 
    industry_id: (integer) 1 
    contact_id: (integer) 1 
    status_id: (integer) 54 
    user_id: (integer) 1 
    qualified_on: (null) NULL
    created_at: (string) 2017-09-22 15:20:13
    updated_at: (string) 2017-10-03 14:07:28
original:protected: 
    (array) [13 elements]
    id: (integer) 1 
    zoho_lead: (integer) 2709828000000210400 
    bname: (string) test
    tname: (string) 
    file: (string) 6cTaDu8FE0Sirwq.png
    source_id: (integer) 11 
    industry_id: (integer) 1 
    contact_id: (integer) 1 
    status_id: (integer) 54 
    user_id: (integer) 1 
    qualified_on: (null) NULL
    created_at: (string) 2017-09-22 15:20:13
    updated_at: (string) 2017-10-03 14:07:28
```

---

Hi all,

Solved my issue, not be correcting anything here, but just by using a transformer.

Thanks for the assistance. Hopefully someone perhaps maybe able to say why this didn't work and solve it anyway.

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: @Jonjie nope, it just makes $lead->id 0 in each instance

Comment: so what does the var_dump($lead) look like?

Comment: @Onyx see edit at end of question

Comment: It does look like the `id` gets hashed `id: (string) A5WQqPZ7j8D`. Possibly at the time of URL creation you might be using this 'id' field which might be type casting it to `0`. Also worth trying to do this `$lead[$key]->id = Hashids::encode((int)$leads->id);`

Comment: @KamalSoni just tried that and it still makes it 0